# Credential Binding does not work in Windows batch command Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, binding, credentials

I'm kind of stuck with the Jenkins credential binding.
I'm using the Bindings tab and created a secret text and the variable for the same is pwd

[image]

and I use the variable in the **"Execute Windows batch command"** step and I'm running the below command on a windows node.

```
echo password is $pwd
```

and the output is always literal

```
password is $pwd
```

Even printing of existing environment variables like $BUILD_NUMBER does not work.

[image]

Why isn't my secret text binding not working? Shouldn't the variable be expanded in my build step? Can anyone please point me to what is the mistake that I'm making here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you did not provide your code, my cristal ball is not working today. only a side note, in batch variable expansion is `%var%` not `$bar`

Comment: Yeah, posting the code might help us, help you. It is impossible for any of us to guess what your code looks like... If I could guess, I would not be here. I can however guess that you set a password somewhere, but you are literally `echo`ing a phrase `password is $pwd` because `$var` is not used in batch, instead we use tokens i.e `%%a` or preset variables i.e `%var%`

Comment: I did provide the code as a picture, anyway, the variable just needs to be printed as %var% Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The var just needs to be printed as `%var%`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using secret text to store password of sql server login and just using %var% didn't work for me 
If you are using the var for password, Use it as **"%var%"**